# how to install Kingsoft Office in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation

I am an Ubuntu 12.04 user and I want to install Kingsoft Office but I don't know how to install it.

Please tell me the procedure to install Kingsoft Office in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find the downloads on their official homepage, therefore I will use a post on OmgUbuntu!.co.uk.

To install KingSoft Office you have to download the .deb from here:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/microsoft-office-clone-wps-updates-interface-improves
When the download is done, simply double click on the .deb file which will open the Ubuntu Software Center, and from here you click "Install". 
When installing is complete, you should be able to find the applications from your Dash.

If you are running Ubuntu 64 bit you'll have to install the package ia32-libs.

The ia32-libs package is available as a free download in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: is the source code not available? I'd like to compile this on a non officially supported architecture.

Comment: Kingsoft Office is not open source, unfortunately.